# MPMoviePlayerViewController has aspect ration wrong for a split second

Tags: ios, iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller

I create a movie using UIImagePickerController using the following:

```
self.cameraUI = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
self.cameraUI.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
self.cameraUI.mediaTypes = @[(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie];
self.cameraUI.delegate = self;
self.cameraUI.videoQuality = UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeMedium;
self.cameraUI.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;
```

In the playback of the video I see that it looks good.

Then I try to load the movie with MPMoviePlayerViewController

```
self.player = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:self.chacha];
self.player.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;

[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:self.player];
```

For a split second when the movie view controller is presented the aspect ratio goes from warped to correct.

[image: For a split second I see this]
[image: Then the screen flickers and I see this]

Anyone know what might be causing this?  I have messed with settings for the movie controller and nothing there I have tried has helped.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you could render it off-screen, or set it's Hidden property to YES until it finishes loading and you're sure the aspect ratio is correct.

I don't have much experience with that player.